# Higher-dimensional analogue of $d^2\phi=2\pi\delta(r)dx \wedge dy$?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, differential-forms

In two dimensions, the following relation exists:

$$d^2\phi=2\pi\delta(r)dx \wedge dy.$$

See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525439/proof-that-d2-phi-2-pi-delta2rdx-wedge-dy-in-polar-coordinates-aro) for proof and discussion.

My question is whether there is a higher-dimensional analogue of this relation. In other words, is there some 1-form $\omega$ such that

$$d^2\omega=\delta(r)dx \wedge dy \wedge dz,$$

up to a numerical factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- $\omega=\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\mathrm{d}x^2\wedge\cdots\wedge \mathrm{d}x^n$ be the usual volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$;
- $\vartheta=x^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}+x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}+\cdots+x^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}$, the generator of dilations about the origin,
- $\iota_v$ the [interior derivative operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) for a vector field $v$.

Then the $(n-1)$-form
$$\delta\Omega=\frac{\iota_{\vartheta}\omega}{r^n}$$
is the element of solid angle about the origin. Away from the origin, the exterior derivative of $\delta \Omega$
$$\begin{split}\mathrm{d}(\delta\Omega)&=-n r^{-n-2}\vartheta^{\sharp}\wedge\iota_{\vartheta}\omega+r^{-n}\mathcal{L}_{\vartheta}\omega\\
&=-n r^{-n}\omega+nr^{-n}\omega\\
&=0
\end{split}$$
where $\mathcal{L}_{v}$ denotes the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) with respect to $v$. But the integral of $\delta\Omega$ on the sphere of radius $a$ centered about the origin is equal to the content of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere:
$$\int_{aS^{n-1}}\delta \Omega=\lvert S^{n-1}\rvert$$
Heuristically, a physicist might use Stokes' theorem to write what's been shown so far as
$$\begin{align}\mathrm{d}(\delta \Omega)&=0\quad (r>0)\\
\int_{aB^n}\mathrm{d}(\delta\Omega) &=\lvert S^{n-1}\rvert
\end{align}$$
where $aB^n$ is the ball of radius $a$ about the origin. On these grounds, the physicist would write
$$\boxed{\mathrm{d}(\delta\Omega)=\lvert S^{n-1}\rvert \delta^{(n)}(x)\omega}\text{.}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I checked and it indeed reduces to the expression in the title for $n=2$ in polar coordinates.

However, I'm afraid I don't understand your calculation of $\mathrm{d}(\delta\Omega)$. In the first line, I understand where the Lie derivative comes from in the second term (Cartan's formula), but I don't understand where the first term comes from or how you got from the first line to the second line. Would you mind explaining that calculation in more detail?

Also, is there a textbook or lecture notes where I can learn more about this and similar results?

Comment: (In particular, what does the "sharp" symbol mean in the first term of the first line, where does it come from when calculating the exterior derivative, and where does it go in the second line?)

Comment: In retrospect, I should have written $\mathrm{d}(\delta\Omega)=\mathrm{d}((\iota_{\vartheta}\omega)/r^n)=\mathrm{d}\iota_{\vartheta}(\omega/r^n)=\mathcal{L}_{\vartheta}(\omega/r^n)=0$, the last equality holding because $\omega/r^n$ is invariant under dilation about the origin. $(\quad)^{\sharp}$ is a [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism), but it doesn't need to be invoked here.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a specific reference. However, this result is intimately connected to de Rham cohomology, Hodge theory, and the theory of harmonic forms, so textbooks in those areas should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks again! I don't understand why $\mathrm{d}((\iota_{\vartheta}\omega)/r^{n})=\mathrm{d}\iota_{\vartheta}(\omega/r^{n})$, could you please explain that step in your calculation?

Comment: Interior derivatives don't "differentiate" anything—they're just a multilinear generalization of contraction between a vector and a $1$-form, so they commute with multiplication by a scalar field.

Comment: Oh, of course, it's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Last question: I understand that when you say "$\omega/r^n$ is invariant under dilation about the origin" you simply mean that both the numerator and denominator receive $n$ powers of the dilation parameter, which then cancels. However, is there any simple/elegant way to actually calculate that Lie derivative and show that it vanishes?

Comment: I think what you're suggesting amounts to calculating $\mathrm{d}(\delta\Omega)$ as was done in my original answer—feasible, but a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Okay, I worked it out myself and I think I understand the calculation. However, from the definition of the musical isomorphism, $\sharp$ takes a 1-form to a vector while $\flat$ takes a vector to a 1-form. Thus, since $\vartheta$ is a vector, shouldn't it be $\vartheta^\flat$ in the first line?

Comment: yeah, you're right, I mixed them up.